# How to issue a Riak Search query?

Tags: erlang, riak

I've been using Riak for about a month now, and I just found out about Riak search.
So I installed it, and inserted a very basic json document to test.

Here is the command i used:

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:8098/riak/json/test -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json
```

where test.json is...

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith"    
 }
```

So according to https://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Riak+Search+-+Indexing+and+Querying+Riak+KV+Data
if i enabled KV searching on this bucket, then when i insert json document, the keys are automatically indexed.

I tried to do a search by using the search utility. i tried

```
/search-cmd search firstName "John"
/search-cmd search "firstName:John"
```

i even tried a curl cmd.

`http://127.0.0.1:8098/solr/json/select?q=firstName:John`

but i'm getting 0 results for all of them.
what exactly am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Your search command needs to be scoped to the "json" index since that's where the document you submitted will be indexed (the Riak Search / KV integration uses the bucket name as the index name). Make sure you install the indexing hook **before** you insert the document.

Try:

```
search-cmd search json firstName:John
```

For a more rapid reply to your question, join the **riak-users** mailing list at [lists.basho.com](http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com).